# Maven not finding artifacts in local repository

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

There's a Maven project I want to use as a dependency for one of my projects. I downloaded the project and ran "mvn install", which installed it to my `/.m2/repository/` folder. I added the dependency in my POM file. When working in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), I can use the dependencies correctly and run my program. Whenever I do a `mvn package` or `mvn install` from the command line (for my program), however, I get:

> Failed to execute goal on project MyProject: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project...

And then it lists each dependency that I specified in my POM.

If I run mvn with `-X`, I see that it's pointing to the right settings.xml file and .m2 folder for my local repository. Does anyone know why it sees the artifacts correctly when I work in my IDE, but not from the command line?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is **too localized**.

Comment: Disagree, pertaining to intellij-idea + maven is not too localized. Very common to ask valid questions pertaining to a particular ide...

Comment: regarding the problem - is your M2_HOME environment variable set? Does M2_HOME/conf refer to the same settings.xml as if you look in the IntelliJ Idea settings on the maven tab: "User settings file" ?

Comment: Can you please post the mvn output ?

Comment: @vikingsteve M2_HOME is indeed set. User settings points to M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml

Comment: @AshutoshJindal Here's the mvn output:

`Failed to execute goal on project jeb: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.zpod.jeb:jeb:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: marytts:marytts:jar:5.1-SNAPSHOT, marytts:marytts-assembly:jar:5.1-SNAPSHOT, marytts:marytts-assembly-builder:jar:5.1-SNAPSHOT, marytts:marytts-assembly-runtime:jar:5.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact marytts:marytts:jar:5.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Ahhh .. I have no idea why the build wouldn't work !! Am guessing **marytts** is the maven project you have downloaded and built locally.  Do you have it imported alongside your own project in Intellij? I was thinking about whether you would have checked 'Resolve Workspace Artifacts' when building your project in IntelliJ. Would it be possible to post your pom or (better still) share your project on Github or something. Would love to see what's going on!